# Triggering a specific action in one viewcontroller from another

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm new to swift and would really appreciate all help I could get! 
My app has two ViewControllers, the first one asks "How are you feeling?" and gives alternatives through buttons. When one of the buttons are tapped are ViewController2 entered and a label is shown.

I have in ViewController2 different arrays of text for each button that are shown in the label randomly. My problem is that the different arrays that are supposed to belong to one specific button each, but are mixed up and shown regardless which button "they belong to". This mixes up the texts and they don't belong to their own buttons/alternatives anymore.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
//the ViewController2 has just been entered by clicking any button in ViewController1

    TextForButton1: NSArray = 
    ["EX1", "EX2", "EX3"]

    let rangeButton1: UInt32 = UInt32(TextForButton1.count)
    let randomNumberButton1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeButton1))
    let StringButton1 = Button1.objectAtIndex(randomNumberButton1)
    self.Label.text = QuoteStringNervous as? String

  //New Button= supposed to be its own text 

    let TextForButton2: NSArray = ["EX4", "EX5", "EX6"]

    let rangeButton2: UInt32 = UInt32(TextForButton2.count)
    let randomNumberButton2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeButton2))
    let StringButton2 = TextForButton2.objectAtIndex(randomNumberButton2)
    self.Label.text = QuoteStringFrustrated as? String
```

**Example of problem is: When Button1 is tapped can "EX4"/"EX5"/"EX6" be shown, instead of just "EX1"/"EX2"/"EX3".**

I know that the UIButtons must be included in the code, but where? I have tried to drag the buttons and create new actions in ViewController2, but it didn't work.

Please help me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, it might be better to use a segue for each button. Then in the first view controller, you can determine which button activated the segue, and modify the button titles in the destinationViewController using prepareForSegue.

For example, drag the buttons into view controller 1, add segue actions to present view controller 2.

In view controller 1's code, add prepareForSegue, add 2 button IBOutlets, and connect the iboutlets to the storyboard.

Also add an IBAction for each button's TouchUpInside that sets a variable in controller 1 to the button pressed.

Now in prepareForSegue check the button pressed, and set the array of text in view controller 2 based on which one it was

As far as your actual question of triggering an action in a different view controller...

There is also NSNotification

in the caller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationNamed:@"DoSomethingNotification" userInfo:nil];
```

in the receiver's viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) forNotificationNamed:@"DoSomethingNotification"]]
```

and add the function to the receiver

```
 -(void)doSomething:(NSNotification*)sender {
     // Perform action here
 }
```

Don't forget to also add this to the receiver:

```
-dealloc {
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) U shouldn't really use NSArrays in Swift ...
2) Check out delegates:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-delegation-and-properties--cms-23445

programming on iOS platform is based around delegates so learning them is the first step of solving your problem.